# images scrolling out of div on window resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/3atxd4uL/

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1  col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" id="innerdiv3_div">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg" alt="">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg" alt="">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg" alt="">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg" alt="">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg" alt="">
        </div>
```

I am trying to create a responsive page. But in this case, when I am resizing the window, the images float out of the container div instead of expanding the containing div. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have set the height for parent container `#innerdiv3`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you looking for:

[WORKING:DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3atxd4uL/9/)

1) The problem was the div **#innerdiv3** must be given the **height:auto** so it could adjust its height when the screen resolution reduces.

2) When you accomplish above you will find that not all img would get on same row, i.e. some goes down(but remains in same div), so now for div **#innerdiv3_div img** i have alter the **max-height = 10% & max-width = 10%;**

3) Now just final touch by giving **margin-bottom:20px**(just random px's you change as you want) to both div's i.e. **#innerdiv3_div** and **#innerdiv3_div img** to leave some space from bottom

**CSS**

```
#innerdiv3{
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#innerdiv3_div img{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;    
    margin-bottom:20px;
    max-height: 10%;
    max-width: 10%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Great ! @user2695383 if this answer fixed the issue, could you please mark the answer as accepted, otherwise could you elaborate on the outstanding issue?

Comment: Are you satisfied with answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an explicit height on `#innerdiv3`.

If you want the number of images in each row to adjust to the width of the viewport, and for the images to always take 100% of the full width media queries is your friend.

https://jsfiddle.net/3atxd4uL/10/

Style each `img` to `float: left` and set a default width of 100% (for the smallest viewport). Then, for each larger breakpoint, style your images to take a gradually smaller fraction of the width (1/2, 1/3, 1/4...):

```
@media (min-width: 200px) {
  #innerdiv3_div img{
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  #innerdiv3_div img{
    width: 33.333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #innerdiv3_div img{
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but what will be the solution? If he removes the height, than the layout is broken. Should he just increase the height? Please try to make your comment an helpful answer.

Comment: That depends on the indended behavior. I assumed OP wanted the images to be 100% wide since OP set `.img-responsive` on them. Should the lines break at appropriate placed depending on viewport width instead?

Comment: He never said he want image 100% width, just to expand the container div (think he thought the one that has white background).

Comment: I adapted my answer inspired by the intention of Bootstraps `img-responsive` class, while trying to keep as close the the original design as possible.